# Pascal triangle with non equiprobable events

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

As many of you will know when flipping n times a coin where each side is equally probable we can calculate the probability of getting x times heads with the triangle of pascal, that would be ${n \choose k}=\frac{n!}{b!(n-b)!}$, then we divide it by $2^n$ and we obtain the probabilities out of 1.
My question is, what if the coin is not well balanced and there is a 70%  probability of getting heads for example, is there a general formula to calculate the probabilities to get x times heads when the two sides aren't equally probable. I know that i can draw a pascal triangle for the 70% case like this:

```
                     1
                0.7     0.3
          0.49     0.42     0.09
```

It consist on multiplying by 0.7 when moving left and 0.3 when moving right and adding the paths that cross but I don't find the formula that it follows, can anyone help me?

Comment: If the probability of getting $H$ is $p$ and you throw the coin $n$ times, then the probability that you get exactly $k$ $H's$ is $\binom nk p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$

Comment: @lulu Do you know where to find the demonstration of this formula?

Comment: this is the so-called binomial distribution.  You can read about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution